# How to create a column having unique values for each row that is list?

Tags: powerbi

I have a csv having this kind of column:

```
column_1
[text1,text2,text2]
[text3,text3,text1]
```

How can I do with powerbi to create a new column that is still a list for each row but containing unique value ?

Expected output:

```
column_1             new_column
[text1,text2,text2]  [text1,text2]
[text3,text3,text1]  [text3,text1]
```

I tried this:

```
let...

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Transform(Text.Split(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Input], "[", "]"), ","), each Text.BetweenDelimiters(_, """", """"))), ","), type text)

in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: List.Distinct(...) is okay, the parentheses was not well places

Comment: Well done. If I understand correctly, it works for any text between [..] and with “, “ as delimiter between the values.

Comment: Do you still need help or have you solved it?